# SE Android app does not work with Verisign OpenID

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, openid

When using a VeriSign OpenID to log into a Stack Exchange site (in a browser), I must first log into the VeriSign site manually. If I don't, all I get is a page explaining that VeriSign won't auto redirect me to their log in page for security reasons.

With a browser, all I do is open another tab and log in, then try again on Stack Exchange.

The app, however, does not let me 'open a tab' to log in. The internal browser used by the SE app does not use cookies from my current phone browser (Chrome).

I was only able to log in by linking my Google account with Stack Exchange, then use that as my log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed as of version 1.0.8 of the application, which has the OpenID providers that require this (Wordpress, Verisign) special cased so that you get an address bar to let you navigate and a <kbd>Back To Login</kbd> button to let you go back to our login process.