# Can't login to Android app with Wordpress openid

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, openid

Just installed the StackExchange app - glad to see it!

As you know, Wordpress do this annoying thing where they interrupt the openid process and ask you to manually go to http://myblog.wordpress.com/admin and login, before giving you a link to continue the openid process.

Although a login via Wordpress option is provided in the Android app, this interrupted flow does not work... there is no way to "use a bookmark or type in the address" from the app.

I don't have any alternative login at the moment.

Comment: WordPress isn't the only one http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195791/se-android-app-does-not-work-with-verisign-openid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 1.0.8 of the application when you tap on Wordpress it gives you an address bar and <kbd>Back To Login</kbd> button so that you can go to Wordpress and login, click the button, then repeat your login attempt.